# Ajax image gallery ("imago"). Scroll position

Tags: javascript

I am using Ajax Image Gallery from this site: http://imago.codeboje.de/.
The problem is that with every image click or lefgt/right arrow click image changes and the scroll moves to the beginning of the page. But I need the scroll to be at the place of the image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the elements you are clicking on are links with and href="#". You'll need to locate what function inside the imago code is being called when you click on one of the elements causing the screen to scroll back up and prevent the default action.  This can usually be accomplished by adding

```
return false;
```

to the end of the function.

Another options would be to remove the link tag from those elements, however, that may also cause some additional modification of the imago source.

I'd go with the first option and have the problem functions return false.